# Display Promotion code as a donation not removed from total

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions

I am using a Promotion code to give 25% of the sale (shipping and taxes not included) to charity. I would like to find a way to display the Total amount (ie: $200) and above it, Donation (ie: $50)
The only thing that I am able to do at the moment is display a discount amount, and it subtracts that amount from the total. Doing it the way I want would display the "discount amount" however not subtract it from the total the customer has to pay.
So if the Promotion code pop1223 is applied this would show up.
Donation:  $50 (25%)
 
Subtotal: $200 (100%)
Taxes: $5
Shipping: $10
Total:  $215
So I have been thinking about what I really want to do after asking this question. The best way I can think to sum this up is that I want to add a new promotion action.
Right now there are 4 actions in the Apply function.
[image]
I want to add a 5th, call it "Percent of Product price as donation"
I could then enter 25 into the "Discount Amount" box.
Then I would just have to edit the code to write it as Donation, not Discount, and not to subtract from the grand total.
That being said, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of effort to modify the shopping cart price rules to achieve a behavior like your are describing here. Why don't just add a text field to cart and/or checkout for a number-input, calculate the actual amount based on the given percentage rate and save it in the quote table from where you can later get the info for mails, history etc.?

Comment: I need to have the code put in the promotions box, because we are capturing via API the same way we would a coupon for our accounting software.  However I would be open to having a Donation text area that would display as 25% if that code was entered? is that possible?